# How can I delete project in actions on google console?

Tags: actions-on-google

I add many testing projects in actions on google console, and now I want to delete them.... But I can't find any delete button to do it. Can I delete project in actions on google console? if yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can follow these steps to delete a project on actions on google console

Goto [Google actions console](https://console.actions.google.com/)

Click on the project you want to delete

[image]

Click on setting icon

[image]

and delete the project

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Sukh! I was so foolish and careless T_T.

Comment: what if we want to just unlink a google actions project created from an existing firebase project? I don't want to delete the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to https://console.actions.google.com/ site
2. Select Your Project
3. Select Modify language in settings
4. Select general tab
5. Delete Project