# How to delete projects on Actions on Google

Tags: project, limit, actions-on-google

I'm playing with Actions on Google and created some projects. I've deleted all of them but I'm unable to create new ones. I receive an error messages stating that I've reached the project limit for my account.  Is there a way to reset this counter once all the projects have been deleted?

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829169/how-can-i-delete-project-in-actions-on-google-console

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the same project on the Google CloudPlatform.
However, I fix this problem by creating a new google account or applying for additional quota for non-paid Cloud Services. I recommend the latter method, since you only need fill the application form and wait 2 work days to get approve.